# Scrolling Div bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scroll, menu

I have a bug with a scrolling div, because it add me an space and I dont know how to eliminate it

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var nav = $(".menu");
    var top = 200;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= top) {

        nav.addClass("-fixo menunu");

    } else {
        nav.removeClass("-fixo menunu");
    }
});
</script>
```

The thing is that the div change from `<div class="menu">` to `<div class="menu -fixo menunu">` and it has to be without the space, like this `<div class="menu-fixo menunu">`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add/remove only a suffix of a class with `addClass` or `removeClass`.

First, remove `.menu` and add `menu-fixo menunu`.

Remove the `var nav` because it only will get the menu element when it is `.menu` and not `.menu-fixo`.

```
var top = 200;
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= top) {
  $(".menu").removeClass("menu").addClass("menu-fixo menunu");
} else {
  $(".menu-fixo").removeClass("menu-fixo menunu").addClass("menu")
}
```

Comment: It work, but when I came back to the top it stays as menu-fixo menunu. What can I do?

Comment: Remove the `var nav` because it will get only the menu element when it is `.menu` and not `.menu-fixo`.

Answer (score 0):

addClass and removeClass will add/remove individual classes rather than operating on all of the classes in the class attribute's string.

Try this

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= top) {
    nav.removeClass("menu");
    nav.addClass("menu-fixo menunu");
} else {
    nav.addClass("menu");
    nav.removeClass("menu-fixo menunu");
}
```

Comment: It work, but when I came back to the top it stays as menu-fixo menunu. What can I do?